How do I test Flutter widget “back” navigation with gestures?
I am doing widget+snapshot tests for a complete Flutter app UI, including navigation between pages. Here is an example.
testWidgets('Navigates to child view and back', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  final widget = buildWidget();
  await widget.setUp(tester, settle: true);

  // Tap on the first child, to trigger navigation to child page.
  await tester.tap(find.type(CompactChildView).first);

  // Make sure we got the navigation request
  verify(() => mockNavigationService.openChild("childId")).called(1);

  // Trigger the navigation and UI update
  mockNavigationState.add(navigateToChild);

  // Let the UI drive its state to completion
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  // Make sure we are on child page now.
  expect(find.byType(ChildView), findsOneWidget);

  // Tap the back button
  await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key("backButton")));

  // Let the UI drive its state to completion
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  // We should now be back at the home screen.
  await widget.expectSnapshot(HomeView, tester);
});

This all works fine.
What I am missing: there are several other ways to navigate “back”, besides using the visible control in the UI. I can think of at least three:

Android “back” swipe
Android device “back” button
iOS interactive “back” swipe from left edge

I would like to test them all in the form of widget testing, by simulating the user’s interaction with the device with gestures and system buttons. I couldn’t immediately think of a way of doing that.
I tried to use WidgetTester.flingFrom to simulate gestures flinging from the left edge of the screen, hoping that they would be converted into the “back” swipes, but had no luck with that.
Is there a way to use Flutter widget testing to simulate the above three ways of navigating “back” in widget tests?

how did you call flingFrom? i used await tester.fling(finder1, Offset(200, 0), 1000);    await tester.pumpAndSettle(); and the fling seems to work

Interesting. I tried this same fling approach but can’t get it to work. Should finder1 match a widget on the left edge of the screen? Because fling starts from center, but the Android back swipe should start from the left side.

finder1 found my widget that is aware of flings, hmm, so maybe your exact Offset you passed to flingFrom is not correct?

Are you picking up the fling yourself up in your widget code? I’m not doing anything special for that, I am using system Navigator where the pages are either MaterialPage or CupertinoPage, and all the back gestures are managed by the system.

i just run that test on PageView widget (final finder1 = find.byType(PageView);) where the current page = 1 so the fling moves the page to index 0, btw did you call await tester.pumpAndSettle(); after fling?

Yep. I always call tester.pumpAndSettle() after any fling calls. I wish there was a complete working example of this entire thing, too bad Flutter doesn’t provide that.

maybe try playing with debugPrintGestureArenaDiagnostics and / or debugPrintRecognizerCallbacksTrace to see if the print anything interesting during the fling (but i am not sure if they are honored during flutter test)

also you can check how they do that: git -C <root_of_your_flutter_installation> grep flingFrom
